# Indexing in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

I have a huge Cosmos DB Collection. It has about 500K records and my RU range is 1000RU/s. I have created a column index for my custom columns. Below is the Index JSON schema.

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
      {
        "path": "/Column1/?",
        "indexes": [
          {
            "kind": "Range",
            "dataType": "String",
            "precision": -1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "path": "/Column2/?",
        "indexes": [
          {
            "kind": "Range",
            "dataType": "String",
            "precision": -1
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
      {
        "path":"/Column4/*"
      }
    ]
}
```

And below is my collection structure.

```
{
    "Column1": "Data1",
    "Column2": "Data2",
    "Column3": "Data3",
    "Column4": "Data4"
}
```

When i trigger the following select query ("`SELECT * FROM r where INDEX_OF(r.Column2,'Data2')>-1`"), it returns the correct values. But it executes it in a batch instead of getting the values from Indexes. For example, the query should return only one record. But it returns blank with continuation Token. I hope the indexing should returns the record from the existing index. Is there anything i have missed?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using INDEX_OF instead of a string compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will not utilize the index because INDEX_OF cannot be served from the index. This is also the case for CONTAINS system function (which is equivalent to INDEX_OF() > -1). For string system functions, only those functions will utilize the index:

- STARTSWITH(str_expr, str_expr)
- LEFT(str_expr, num_expr) = str_expr
- SUBSTRING (str_expr, num_expr, num_expr) = str_expr, but only if first num_expr is 0

Comment: Thank you and appreciate your quick reply. The details you have provided, helped a lot in utilizing index. Along with this we need another help regarding retrieving total count of the records. The below given is the query used to retreive total count of available records in the collection. SELECT COUNT(1) FROM c where c.Column1 IN ('Data2'). Here, this queries retrieves data from multiple sets with continuation token. This delays the total count result. Could you please let me know if we can use the indexing to increment the query permformance without increasing the RU's.

Answer (score -2):

Understand RU limitation, you have 1000 RU mean, you can't read more than 1000 document (1kb doc size) within a seconds

You may have 2 solutions:

1. You could raise the RUs setting. (temporary increase RU)
2. You could keep looking for next set of results via continuation token and keep on adding it so that you will get total count.(Probably in sdk)

Comment: @DavidMakogon Can you explain bit more